# The "form" extension is not enabled

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony4, sonata

> "form" extension is not enabled

I got the above error when i override listAction of Sonata Admin Bundle.

Could someone have the same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$twig->getExtension(FormExtension::class)` instead of `$twig->getExtension('form')` where `FormExtension` is included by `use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension;`